# Cannot resolve PlusClient

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I try to integrate my android-application to g+. I try to add PlusClient to initialize it. But AndroidStudio says : `Cannot resolve PlusClient`.
I added these import-header:

```
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
```

Also, I tryed to add these import-header:

```
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
```

but AndroidStudio cannot find `PlusClient` after `.plus.`
I'm using 22 api.
How to fix it? Does Api still support PlusClient? And is any differences bettween Plus and PlusClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `PlusClient` is not in the Android documentation, so it probably doesn't exist. Use[`GoogleApiClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html)

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
     .addApi(Plus.API)
     .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
     .setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
     .build();
client.connect();
```

Comment: i cant resolve Plus...i am using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0' in my gradle

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update your google play services to version 23.You should be adding google play services as library project to you project

Answer (score 0):

The PlusClient can't be found  after updating the buid tool to 23.0.2, So use GoogleApiClient instead.